# Bamboo Plans incompatible after update?

Tags: deployment, bamboo

We have updated Bamboo to Version `5.9.7 build 5920 - 14 Oct 15`. I don't know yet the version before, my boss will check tomorrow. It should be `5.7.2`.

After updating all relations between plans and Repositories were lost which I've updated manually ...

But all tasks are also lost. I've looked up in DB and they are still there, as XML ... So perhaps the structure wasn't migrated and is incompatible?

Can someone point me to the solution or help me to find the issue? We have more then 60 plans and reconfiguration by hand would cost a lot of time ... So an automatic migration or fix would be very helpful.

Comment: Also all executables are missing. My boss has moved the installation to another place during update and changed the owner of bamboo.

Comment: How did you migrate? Did you install new version at different location and use old BAMBOO_HOME or upgraded at same location?

Answer (score 0):

Create request at support.atlassian.com, looks like some wrong issue during migration